# Animate individual tiles in tile map

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, tile

I am working on cocos2d game that use tile maps. I need to change the opacity of individual tile. I used following code,

```
CCSprite *sprite = [metaLayer tileAt:tilePos];
CCFadeIn* fadeOut = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:2];
[sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:fadeOut, nil]];
```

When i run this code this animation effect all tiles use this texture. Only i need handle individual tiles using coordinate. Is there any solution for this problem in tile maps.

Comment: if you try to remove that particular sprite will it remove all tiles with same texture? (it shouldn't...) as far as I know the only way to refer to a single tile is tileAt. When you call tileAt the CCSprite will be part of the tilemap as one tile, so it is strange why this is happening

Comment: Yes, It's my mistake. Now it's working.